# Type error in model.fit() using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Getting type error when running this code:

```py
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)
```

```py
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried updating my `tf` version and `numpy` version,
but the error still persists.

Here is the complete code:

```
x_train, y_train = [], []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x - prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0, 2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0, 2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Try printing your `x_train` and `y_train` before the training of model and see what you get

Comment: It's just a typo as in the second and third dropout layers you used `0, 2` instead of `0.2` as the dropout rate. If you use `Dropout(0.2)` instead of `Dropout(0, 2)` everywhere then your code will work as expected.

Comment: @Mohammad Faheem, Yes, as rightly mentioned by @Flavia Giammarino. `Dropout` layer expect `rate` and it's value should be `float between 0 and 1 (i.e, Fraction of the input units to drop)`. So, please change `rate` value from `(0,2)` to `(0.2)`. Thanks!